# Load CSV with multiple JSON (Dicts) in a same row on a pandas dataframe

Tags: json, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I'm trying to read a csv file with pandas, but de csv have this format for each row:
`{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "646759973384fd67d8dc6aa5" }, "prefixoVeiculo" : "JSL-793", "prefixoGrua" : "MA06", "idOrigemViagem" : "60c7bc2d570f98748404f2b4", "idFrenteCarregamento" : "60cb7ad8570f987484052a8f", "idCercaEletronicaDestinoViagem" : "60c7b75477fc56737ca431cd", "dataInicioTrajeto" : { "$date" : 1684494743869 }, "idDestinoViagem" : "6467592a18ae7e2da4d18823", "usuario" : "diego.camargo.jsl@fornecedores.klabin.com.br", "justificativa" : "balancaStatus8", "transportadora" : "JSL S/A  ", "createdDate" : { "$date" : 1684494743869 }, "historicoStatusViagem" : [ { "createdDate" : { "$date" : 1684494743822 }, "statusViagem" : "TRAJETO_VAZIO", "usuario" : "obterHistoricosStatusViagemParaNovoDespacho" }, { "createdDate" : { "$date" : 1684498175000 }, "statusViagem" : "PESAGEM", "createdDateDB" : { "$date" : 1684498185660 }, "usuario" : "balancaStatus4", "numRecebimento" : "0000413534" }, { "createdDate" : { "$date" : 1684498175000 }, "statusViagem" : "FINALIZADO", "createdDateDB" : { "$date" : 1684502881506 }, "usuario" : "balancaStatus8", "numRecebimento" : "0000413534" } ], "isLongaDistancia" : false, "statusKlazeCargo" : [  ], "_class" : "com.klabin.veiculorota.core.entities.DespachoCaminhao" }`

I tried just to read without parameters:

`df = pd.read_csv('despachoCaminhao_14_08.csv')`

the result:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M4zXv.png)

Tried this:

`df = pd.read_csv('despachoCaminhao_14_08.csv', converters={'historicoStatusViagem': lambda x:json.loads(x.replace('$date', 'date')),'createdDate': lambda x:json.loads(x.replace('$date','date')),'dataInicioTrajeto': lambda x:json.loads(x.replace('$date', 'date'))})`

the result:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M4zXv.png)

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

You have Json data, not CSV. To load the Json file into pandas dataframe you can use this example:

```py
import json

with open("your_file.json", "r") as f_in:
    data = json.load(f_in)

df = pd.json_normalize(data).explode("historicoStatusViagem")
df = pd.concat(
    [
        df,
        df.pop("historicoStatusViagem")
        .apply(pd.Series)
        .add_prefix("historicoStatusViagem."),
    ],
    axis=1,
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  prefixoVeiculo prefixoGrua            idOrigemViagem      idFrenteCarregamento idCercaEletronicaDestinoViagem           idDestinoViagem                                       usuario   justificativa transportadora  isLongaDistancia statusKlazeCargo                                                 _class                  _id.$oid  dataInicioTrajeto.$date  createdDate.$date historicoStatusViagem.createdDate historicoStatusViagem.statusViagem                historicoStatusViagem.usuario historicoStatusViagem.createdDateDB historicoStatusViagem.numRecebimento
0        JSL-793        MA06  60c7bc2d570f98748404f2b4  60cb7ad8570f987484052a8f       60c7b75477fc56737ca431cd  6467592a18ae7e2da4d18823  diego.camargo.jsl@fornecedores.klabin.com.br  balancaStatus8      JSL S/A               False               []  com.klabin.veiculorota.core.entities.DespachoCaminhao  646759973384fd67d8dc6aa5            1684494743869      1684494743869          {'$date': 1684494743822}                      TRAJETO_VAZIO  obterHistoricosStatusViagemParaNovoDespacho                                 NaN                                  NaN
0        JSL-793        MA06  60c7bc2d570f98748404f2b4  60cb7ad8570f987484052a8f       60c7b75477fc56737ca431cd  6467592a18ae7e2da4d18823  diego.camargo.jsl@fornecedores.klabin.com.br  balancaStatus8      JSL S/A               False               []  com.klabin.veiculorota.core.entities.DespachoCaminhao  646759973384fd67d8dc6aa5            1684494743869      1684494743869          {'$date': 1684498175000}                            PESAGEM                               balancaStatus4            {'$date': 1684498185660}                           0000413534
0        JSL-793        MA06  60c7bc2d570f98748404f2b4  60cb7ad8570f987484052a8f       60c7b75477fc56737ca431cd  6467592a18ae7e2da4d18823  diego.camargo.jsl@fornecedores.klabin.com.br  balancaStatus8      JSL S/A               False               []  com.klabin.veiculorota.core.entities.DespachoCaminhao  646759973384fd67d8dc6aa5            1684494743869      1684494743869          {'$date': 1684498175000}                         FINALIZADO                               balancaStatus8            {'$date': 1684502881506}                           0000413534
```